# dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_fuzzy)

Tags: python, cython

I am using Python3.4 and I am trying to install the module fuzzy

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fuzzy.
```

Since it is mentioned it works only for Python2, I tried to convert it using cython. These are the steps that I followed:

1. cython fuzzy.pyx
2. gcc -g -02 -fpic `python-config --cflags` -c fuzzy.c -o fuzzy.o
3. did the same for double_metaphone.c
4. gcc -shared -o fuzzy.so fuzzy.o double_metaphone.o `python-config --libs`

When I tried to import fuzzy I got an error:

```
dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_fuzzy)
```

What is the issue? Is this because of the python2 and python3 clash? How to resolve this?

Comment: Try swapping "python-config" for "python3-config" or "python3.4-config"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This was solved with a quick comment, but posted as an answer for the sake of giving a bit more detail...

The very short answer is to replace all instances of `python-config` for `python3-config` or `python3.4-config`.

*Unnecessary detail follows*

OP was trying to use a Pyrex module in Python 3 (this isn't especially clear from the question), and hence rebuilding it in Cython is a sensible approach to take, since Cython was originally based on Pyrex.

Cython generates code that should compile to work in Python 2 or 3, depending on which headers are included. `python-config` generates relevant compiler/linker options for the default version of Python on the system which at the time of writing is typically Python 2 (on my system it includes `-I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7`). Therefore it builds the module for Python 2. Using the `python3.4-config` ensures that the right version is included.

In the changeover from Python 2 to Python 3 the function called when C modules are imported was changed from `init<modulename>` to `PyInit_<modulename>`, presumably to help ensure that you can only import modules built for the correct version. Therefore when the module is built with Python 2 it only creates `initfuzzy`, and therefore fails to find `PyInit_fuzzy` on import.