# Cython Compilation Error: dynamic module does not define module export function

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am building a package in Cython. I am using the following as the structure for `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy
import scipy

extensions = [
    Extension("xxxxx",["xxxx/xxxxx.pyx"],
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include(),"."]),
    Extension("nnls",["xxxxx/xxxxx.pyx"],
              include_dirs=[numpy.get_include(),"."]),
]

setup(
    name='xxxxxx',
    version='0.0.0',
    description='''********''',
    url='xxxxxxx',
    author='xxxxx',
    author_email='xxxxx',
    packages=[
        'xxxxx',
    ],
    install_requires=[
        'cython',
        'numpy',
        'scipy',
    ],
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
)
```

However, I am getting an error upon installation in Python 3. It is working in Python 2 however, it is not compiling in Python 3 having the following error:

> dynamic module does not define module export function

How can I solve this problem? Is the structure of the `setup.py` the reason why this is not compiling?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call setup.py with Python 3 (`python3 setup.py build_ext`, maybe `--inplace`). It's because Python 3 defines a different name for the `init` function called when the module starts, and so you need to build it using Python 3 to ensure the correct name is generated.

See [dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_fuzzy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657319/dynamic-module-does-not-define-init-function-pyinit-fuzzy/29685650#29685650) and [How to specify Python 3 source in Cython's setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603628/how-to-specify-python-3-source-in-cythons-setup-py) for slightly more detail (it's bordering on a duplicate of these questions, but isn't quite in my view)

Answer (score 6):

I experienced this and found that I had to use the same name of .pyx as the module name, e.g.

makefile:

```
# (default)
# INSTALL_DIR:=/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
# (my venv)
INSTALL_DIR:=/home/<username>/python3_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
all:
    sudo python3 setup_myproj.py install --install-lib ${INSTALL_DIR}
```

setup_myproj.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext = Extension("myproj",
                sources=["myproj.pyx", "myCppProjFacade.cpp"],
                <etc>
                language="c++"
               )

setup(name="myproj",
      version="0.0.1",
      ext_modules=cythonize(ext))
```

client module, run after installing to venv

```
import myproj as myCppProjWrapper
...
```

I also found that if the "myproj" names are different, under `<python-lib-dir>/<python-vers>/site-packages` the .so and .egg-info names are different and the client fails to load it.

In addition I found that the client's environment does not need to have the `cython` package installed.

Comment: Would you comment on what OS you were on?

Comment: @jxramos  Debian Linux

Comment: holiness, the same thing here, not allowed to change the name of the .so file

Comment: You saved my life, thanks! But why this is required?

Comment: I've no idea; it just happened to be what I found to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for `torchvision`. FIxed it by downgrading the installation versions:

```
pip install torch==1.2.0+cu92 torchvision==0.4.0+cu92 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Comment: Non relevant to the question