# Packaging python with cython extension

Tags: python, package, cython, setuptools

I'm trying to build a package that uses both python and cython modules. The problem I'm having deals with imports after building and installing where I'm not sure how to make files import from the `.so` file generated by the build process.

Before building my folder structure looks like this

```
root/
├── c_integrate.c
├── c_integrate.pyx
├── cython_builder.py
├── __init__.py
├── integrator_class.py
├── integrator_modules
│   ├── cython_integrator.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── integrator.py
│   ├── numba_integrator.py
│   ├── numpy_integrator.py
│   ├── quadratic_error.png
│   ├── report3.txt
│   ├── report4.txt
│   └── report5.txt
├── report6.txt
├── setup.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_integrator.py
```

Building with `python3.5 setup.py build` gives this new folder in `root`

```
root/build/
├── lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
│   ├── c_integrate.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
│   ├── integrator_modules
│   │   ├── cython_integrator.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── integrator.py
│   │   ├── numba_integrator.py
│   │   └── numpy_integrator.py
│   └── test
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_integrator.py
```

The `setup.py` file looks like this

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages
import numpy

setup(
    name = "integrator_package",
    author = "foo",
    packages = find_packages(),
    ext_modules = [Extension("c_integrate", ["c_integrate.c"])],
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
)
```

My question is then: how do I write import statements of the functions from the `.so` file into `ìntegrator_class.py` in `root` and `cython_integrator` and `test_integrator` located in the `build` directory. Appending to `sys.path` seems like a quick and dirty solution that I don't much like.

EDIT:
As pointed out in the comments I haven't installed the package. This is because I don't know *what to write* to import from the `.so` file

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048732/python-setup-py-develop-vs-install) relevant?

Comment: Seems like you don't install the package you've built like @DavidW pointed out. Issue `pip install path/to/root/` or `pip install --editable=path/to/root/` to marry the built files with python.

Comment: Yup, I haven't installed it - but my problem is that since the `.so` file is named platform specific I don't know how to import it. Especially since the `lib.linux...` folder doesn't have an `__init__.py` file. Aditionally: after I install and just try to rename the `.so` file and import it raises `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In no specific order:

1. The file setup.py is typically located *below* the root of a project. Example:

   ```
   library_name/
       __init__.py
       file1.py
   setup.py
   README
   ```
2. Then, the build directory appears alongside the project's source and not in the project source.
3. To import the file c_integrate.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so in Python, just import "c_integrate". The rest of the naming is taken care of automatically as it is just the platform information. See [PEP 3149](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/)
4. A valid module is one of

   1. a directory with a `modulename/__init__.py` file
   2. a file named `modulename.py`
   3. a file named `modulename.PLATFORMINFO.so`

   of course located in the Python path. So there is no need for a `__init__.py` file for a compiled Cython module.

   For your situation, move the Cython code *in* the project directory and either do a relative import `import .c_integrate` or a full `from integrator_modules import c_integrate` where the latter only works when your package is *installed*.

A few of this information can be found in my blog post on Cython modules http://pdebuyl.be/blog/2017/cython-module.html

I believe that this should let you build a proper package, comment below if not.

EDIT: to complete the configuration (see comments below), the poster also

1. Fixed the module path in the setup.py file so that it is the full module name starting from the PYTHONPATH: `Extension("integrator_package.integrator_modules.c_integrat‌​or", ["integrator_package/integrator_modules/c_integrator.c"]` instead of `Extension("c_integrate", ["c_integrate.c"])]`
2. Cythonize the module, build it and use with a same Python interpreter.

Further comment: the setup.py file can cythonize the file as well. Include the `.pyx` file instead of the `.c` file as the source.

```
cythonize(Extension('integrator_package.integrator_modules.c_integrat‌​or',
          ["integrator_package/integrator_modules/c_integrator.pyx"],
          include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I made changes to the tree so it looks like you suggested. I now get an error on importing the cython module `ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_c_integrator)`. The setup file builds extensions as `ext_modules = [Extension("integrator_package.integrator_modules.c_integrator", 
    ["integrator_package/integrator_modules/c_integrator.c"]`

Comment: Solved with the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723206/cython-compilation-error-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-function) thread. Turns out `cython` is build sensitive