# cythonize dynamic module does not define module export function

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

```
$ cythonize -a -i hello.pyx

running build_ext
building 'hello' extension
...
```

Now I have a hello.so file, as well as the other ones (hello.pyx, hello.c)

When I then try to import the function:

```
$ python
Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Mar  6 2017, 11:58:13) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_hello)
>>>
```

I know this has been asked before (link below), but it seems the solution was to run python3, which I am doing already, so I don't know how to fix my problem
[Cython Compilation Error: dynamic module does not define module export function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723206/cython-compilation-error-dynamic-module-does-not-define-module-export-function)

I should add the cythonize version I am using:
$ cython --version
Cython version 0.24

Comment: Possible that `cythonize` is pointing to a python 2 install?  Check the output of `$ which cythonize`

Comment: thanks but I don't really understand how to check completely. I am using my local machine as logged into a remote server. I did which cythonize and got: ~/.conda/envs/mypython/bin/cythonize .  I tried also updating the cython by doing conda install cython
    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    cython-0.26                |           py35_0         7.0 MB

Comment: @chrisb , ok I think that isn't the problem because it is pointing to a python 3 install:  $ head `which cythonize`
#!/u1/usr/.conda/envs/mypython/bin/python
if _name_ == '_main_':
import sys
import Cython.Build.Cythonize

sys.exit(Cython.Build.Cythonize.main())

(mypython) remoteserver01 $ /u1/usr/.conda/envs/mypython/bin/python --version
Python 3.5.3 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.

Comment: When the extension is built, it logs the build commands. Does it take python3 or python2 libraries?

Comment: Have a look at the output of `objdump -T hello.something.so`. You're interested in function names with `init` or `Init` in. This might give you an idea what has happened (edit the `something` to match your file!)