# Replace python config files for C++ extension

Tags: python, c++, distutils

I'm trying to write a simple module in C++ and import it into Python. However, when I try to import the module using `import greet`, I get a `ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_greet)` error.

After reading another SO question related to this problem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657319/dynamic-module-does-not-define-init-function-pyinit-fuzzy)) I thought that I may be having version problems (since I'm using Python3.5). But then again, every command I'm using to build and install, I'm using with Python3.5, so how could I be having version problems? (`python3.5 build setup.py` and `python3.5 setup.py install`).

I'm trying to create a modified version of the simple project described in the Python Docs ([here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/building.html)), and everything works fine until I try to import the module.

Here is my `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

greet_module = Extension('greet',
        define_macros=[('MAJOR_VERSION','1'),
                   ('MINOR_VERSION','0')],
        include_dirs=['/usr/local/include'],
        # clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to
        # libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9
        sources=['greet.cpp'])

setup (name='Greet_Package',
       version='1.0',
       description='This is a demo package',
       author='ralston',
       author_email='null',
       url='https://google.com',
       long_description='''This is really just a demo package''',
       ext_modules=[greet_module])
```

Could it be related to my `include_dirs` parameter? My Python3.5 isn't actually installed there, but I tried putting my Python3.5 path in `include_dirs` but I got the same error. When I build `setup.py` here's my output:

```
running build
running build_ext
building 'greet' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DMAJOR_VERSION=1 -DMINOR_VERSION=0 -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -c greet.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/greet.o
creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5
/usr/bin/clang++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g     build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/greet.o -L/usr/lib -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/greet.cpython-35m-darwin.so
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was having this same exact error and this post helped me fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305731/compiler-cant-find-py-initmodule-is-it-deprecated-and-if-so-what-should-i